# Using task results in downstream task in airflow

Tags: python, variables, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have a airflow DAG in which i need to list the S3 object keys and use them in downstream tasks

I added S3 keys in a prefix to a list at the start of the task. This list is created on global level. After the task is completed, when I'm printing list, I'm able to print keys. But after the task is completed and when I'm trying to access the same list I'm not able to access the same list. Instead I'm getting the empty list that is initially created. I observed the same with variables declared as global in task. I have created the variable with name `start_timestamp` and made it global in first task and assigned some value. When I'm accessing this variable in downstream task, I see the old value, not the one which I updated in the earlier task.

what is the reason for this? and is there a way that we can access these variables with out sending them to XCom?

Comment: Can you add your DAG please? How you access the output returned from the task? Global variables won't work because each task is executed in separate process. The way to pass such information between task is either via XCom, Variable or external stage like S3 buckets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow [execution](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/index.html) is not meant to share variables, even if they're global. Airflow could run different tasks in different workers, so sharing memory between those is not defaulted.

That being said, and if you don't want to use `XComs` (the best practice for little pieces of data), the only option you have is to use `Variables`. From [Airflow's best practice documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html?highlight=variable#variables) you can see that it's recommended to use it if you can template them (and that depends on the operator).

If you want to go with that option, you have to set the variable and get it when you need to use it. I want to make it very clear: it's not recommended to set and get a variable in the main definition of the DAG because it creates a connection to the metadata database. I would go with `XComs` if possible.